# ¿Como llenar inputs con petición ajax en laravel?

Tags: html, laravel, ajax, api

Hola buen día tengo esta tabla de productos

```html
class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'productos';
    
     protected $fillable = [
        'category_id',
        'titulo',
        'precio'
    ];
    
    protected $primarykey = 'id';
    
}
```

y en su controlador le hice una consulta para traer los datos según su id

```html
    public function byProducto($id){
        return DB::table('productos as p')
             ->select('p.id','p.titulo','p.precio','p.created_at','p.updated_at')
             ->where('p.id', '=', $id)
             ->get();;
    }
```

y en la ruta api puse lo siguiente

```html
Route::get('/producto/{id}/producto','ProductoController@byProducto');
```

y si me ejecuta bien la consulta pero ahora lo que quiero es traer esos datos que tengo y rellenarlos en mis inputs,
la idea es que cuando se seleccione un producto, los demás campos se rellenen con la información que tiene ese producto (titulo, precio)

esto es lo que me retorna en la consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero llamar esos datos que tengo pero aun no logro hacerlo

este es mi script

```js
 $(function(){
        $('#pid_articulo').on('change',onSelectProducto);
    });

    
    function onSelectProducto(){
        var id = $(this).val();
         $.get('api/producto/' + id + '/producto', function(data){  
            
                   console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function(id, opt) {
                     var html = '';
                    html = '<input value="' + data.titulo +'">'
                    $('#input_1').val(html);
                    $("#input_2").val(data.precio);
                });
            
         });
        
    }
```

lo intente de esa manera pero no logro tener éxito

Agradezco todas las respuestas

Answer (score 1):

En el controlador puedes hacer la consulta mas pequeña, quedandote asi

```
//Si existe te traerá un objeto, si no, devuelve null
return Producto::find($id);
```

En javascript puedes buscar si te regreso un objeto o null

```
if(data !== null) {
$("#input_2").val(data.precio);
....
}
```

No puedes meter un elemento de html a otro como lo tienes en input_1

Comment: Agradezco tu comentario, ya pude resolverlo

Answer (score 0):

ni idea de que quieres lograr, llenar el `select`?, o solo los campos `input` en cualquier caso, primeramente `data` es una `lista` o `array`, no pudes usarlo directamente.

Tienes que usar un indice

```
$('#input_1').val(data[0].titulo);
$("#input_2").val(data[0].precio);
```

usas `data[0]` en caso de que esperabas un único valor, pero si era una lista y querias llenar el `select`.

```
data.forEach(producto=> $("#input_1").append('<option value="'+producto.id+'">'+producto.titulo+'</option>') );
```

Comment: Gracias, ya pude resolverlo

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre resolver lo gracias por las respuestas lo hice de la siguiente manera

```js
        function onSelectName(){
        var name = $(this).val();        
         $.get('api/producto/' + name + '/producto', function(datas){
            var html_select = '';
            for (var a = 0; a < datas.length; ++a)
            html_select += (datas[a].titulo);
          $('#pid_articulo').val(html_select);

         });
```